# Is this utility class with 2 static methods threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, static-methods

The following Utility class calls within itself the same static methods, but has no shared global variables. But it looks like the method nameTo() is "shared" and an issue. Am I right with it, and that it's unsafe?

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static MyObject create_1(boolean b)
    {
        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        o.setName(nameTo(b));           
        return o;
    }

    public static MyObject create_2(boolean b)
    {
        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        o.setName(nameTo(b));           
        return o;
    }

    public static String nameTo(boolean b)
    {
        if(b)
            return "NameA";
        else
            return "NameB";         
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. You aren't using threads anyway, why do you think that would be an issue?

Comment: Other than the fact that the bodies of `create_1()` and `create_2()` appear to be identical, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this.

Comment: @MrLore Should be an answer.

Comment: It's an Utility class which might be called hundreds of times parallel. So maybe the nameTo() methods can be overwritten by different boolean values? The create () methods can be called with different booleans, which will be forwarded to the nameTo()

Comment: @MrLore You can't say OP is not using threads as the code sample provided is only one class, you don't know how it is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All static methods are shared between threads. And as the `nameTo()` method **does not have any shared state** that it is using and hence **it is Thread safe**.

```
class Utility{

  private static int sharedValue; //something like counter of how many times nameTo() is called

  public static String nameTo(boolean b){
     //logic

     sharedValue++; //this will not be thread safe as it is shared state and being updated  in parallel

  }
}
```

Comment: So does that mean I can have any number of methods within the static class which call each other (using all kinds of objects as parameters) and it's still thread-safe, just because I don't use some kind of global variable (that could be modified by one of the methods) within the same class?

Comment: Yes that class can be called thread safe, but nothing can be said about the objects that are being passed as the arguments to the methods of the class, they themselves can be non-threadsafe.

Answer (score 3):

Since your `nameTo()` method is stateless, there is no problem with it in multi-threaded contexts. Code may be shared between threads as much as you like. It’s the data which matters.

Answer (score 1):

You have no data that is in a `global state`, so I dont see any thread-safety issues.
None of the methods changes any `shared data`.